# What is the meaning of the phrase "made out to", in the current context?

Tags: phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context

I have received a letter which has the following sentence. The letter is about reimbursement of my travel costs to their location.

> Please note that for tax reasons all invoices have to be made out to the company.

What is the meaning of the term *made out to* in the current context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the invoices must be addressed to the company and not, presumably, to any indidvidual within the company.